# Switch on custom table view cell won't stay highlighted

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a switch on a custom table view cell that allows users to sign up for notifications and am experiencing the following issue:

If a user turns on notifications by clicking the switch at index 0 and then scrolls to the bottom (pushing index 0 off the page) and then scrolls back up, the option at index 0 that they just turned on will show once again as turned off.

It seems that the cell is remembering the setting from when it was first loaded (switch being turned off) and reverts to that when the cell scrolls off the page and then back on.

How can I make the switch on the custom cell remember that it's been changed? Maybe an issue with the cells being reused?

Comment: You would need some part of our data model to 'remember' the switch setting for each data model item, then set the switch accordingly in `cellForRow` delegate method. You must do the setup every time `cellForRow` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ensure that the data is stored in order to prevent the issue. I would check in the `viewDidLoad` for a value, update the value on selecting the switch, then assign the value when `cellForRow` instantiates the row.

```
var toggleValue : Bool? // set variable to be used in class

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // TODO: load value from wherever you store this value... User Defaults, Core Data, etc.,
    if let value = storedData.value {
        toggleValue = value
    } else { toggleValue = false }

}
```

Then when you load the cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.switch.setOn(toggleValue!, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Then in your function where you handle the toggle for the switch you need to update the value of the `toggleValue` variable. Something like this:

```
// obviously this wont work on it's own. You'll need an action or to observe the switch and call the function when appropriate.
func doSwitch() { 
    // check toggleValue and swap true/false
    if switch.isOn {
        toggleValue = false
    } else { toggleValue = true } 
    // TODO: store the value somewhere like User Defaults  
    switch.setOn(toggleValue!, animated: true) // perform toggle
}
```